# Scikit-learn QuantileRegressor memory allocation error. No issue with statsmodel QuantReg with the same data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels, quantile-regression

I'm trying to fit a quantile regression model to my input data. I would like to use sklearn, but I am getting a memory allocation error when I try to fit the model. The same data with the statsmodels equivalent function is working fine.

The error I get is the following:

```
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 55.9 GiB for an array with shape (86636, 86636) and data type float64
```

It doesn't make any sense, my X and y are shapes (86636, 4) and (86636, 1) respectively.

Here's my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.linear_model import QuantileRegressor

training_df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/training_df.csv") # 86,000 rows

FEATURES = [
    "feature_1",
    "feature_2",
    "feature_3",
    "feature_4",
]

TARGET = "target"


# STATSMODELS WORKS FINE WITH 86,000, RUNS IN 2-3 SECONDS.
model_statsmodels = sm.QuantReg(training_df[TARGET], training_df[FEATURES]).fit(q=0.5)

# SKLEARN GIVES A MEMORY ALLOCATION ERROR, OR TAKES MINUTES TO RUN IF I SIGNIFICANTLY TRIM THE DATA TO < 1000 ROWS.
model_sklearn = QuantileRegressor(quantile=0.5, alpha=0)
model_sklearn.fit(training_df[FEATURES], training_df[TARGET])
```

There error I get is the following:

I've checked the sklearn documentation and pretty sure my inputs are fine as dataframes, I get the same issues with NDarrays. So not sure what the issue is. Is it possible there's an issue with something under-the-hood?

[Here][1] is the scikit-learn documentation for QunatileRegressor.

Many thanks for any help / ideas.
[1]: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.QuantileRegressor.html

Comment: Messages that say a huge amount of RAM cannot be allocated *always* indicate you have mixed up the dimensions of a matrix.  "...shape (86636, 86636)..." in the message confirms this.

Comment: I know I thought that, but if I run training_df[FEATURES].shape and training_df[TARGET].shape, I get (86636, 4) and (86636,) respectively. This matches perfectly with the expected input param shapes:
From the documentation:

Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training data.

        y : array-like of shape (n_samples,)
            Target values.

Comment: This is a software problem.  Begin by creating a minimum reproducible example--it's hard to get any help when you require people to work with huge matrices.  Change your dimension from 86636 to 1, 2, or 3, and look at what the software is doing.

Comment: QuantileRegressor.fit() is compiling an array  A_eq = np.concatenate([X, -X, eye, -eye], axis=1), which is passed to the linear programmer alogrithm. Where X is the input data, and eye is a matrix of 0s with 1s on the diagonal of size (N, N) where N is the number of samples. This gives an input matrix size of (N, 2*F + 2*N), where F is the number of features which for a large sample size is prohibitively large.

I don't know why such a large matrix is required to solve the linear regression. The statsmodel quantreg uses iterative weighted least squares, so I will be using this I think!

Comment: The scikit-learn team describes this as a known limitation. See this GitHub issue: [QuantileRegressor unable to allocate memory for large datasets](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22922)

Comment: @dipetkov thank you for that! that explains the issue nicely. I will keep an eye on this and use statsmodels in the meantime!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sklearn QuantileRegressor class uses linear programming to solve  the quantile regression problem which is much more computationally expensive than iterative reweighted least squares as used by statsmodel QuantReg class.

Here is a github issue for the same problem:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22922

Thanks [dipetkov](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/237901/dipetkov) for the link.